# How to shrink the user menu?

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-fallback

I am running `gnome-session-fallback` and I want my panel to have a height of 24 pixel, that can be easily configured, except for one problem maker, the user menu:

[image: User menu]

Unlike all other applets, the user menu has a minimum size of around 30 pixel, which make the panel to ignore my 24 pixel setting and forces it to 30 pixel.

How can I either shrink the user menu or get back the old system menu, so that I don't need the user menu?

I already tried to change the icons (i.e. `user-available-symbolic.svg`, ...), but even without the icons the thing stays up at 30px.

Comment: svg's are scale-able vector images so it's unlikely that the those icons themselves would influence size the way png's might have.

Comment: This worked for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel

Answer (score 2):

The indicator applet from Unity has been ported to gnome, it is smaller than the default one, I use it in gnome 3's fallback mode to get around the issue with the size of the bar. Try running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-applet-complete indicator-applet-session`
```

[There are some screen shots and things here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/indicator-applet-ported-to-gnome-3-can.html).

You can then add this from the 'add to panel' menu.