# How Can I Set the Unhide Speed of the Gnome-Classic Panel?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

I have installed gnome-session-fallback. I followed Håkon A. Hjortland's excellent instructions from [How to customize the gnome classic panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel), but autohide (and even more importantly unhide) is still at the default overly slow speed. How can I set the unhide speed of my top and bottom panels?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use dconf-editor from the package [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) and set the properties manually. When the package is installed, press alt+f2 and run dconf-editor. Find Org > Gnome > gnome-panel > layout > toplevels. That will contain "bottom-panel" and "top-panel", each with its own settings, like animation-speed, auto-hide, auto-hide-size, hide-delay, etc.

Play with those settings and restart gnome-panel by pressing alt+f2 and running `killall gnome-panel`.

Comment: You should accept the answer, then, so that other users see that it is answered and solved.

Comment: What is the max value for hide-delay?, I'm trying to do this - [How to get the ‘wingpanel’ in ubuntu with the current gnome panel](http://justinstories.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/how-to-get-the-wingpanel-in-ubuntu-with-the-current-gnome-panel/) but does not allow me the value indicated in the guide. I found a way to achieve the same effect but not the best, change the value of the option y-bottom to 1055 (my monitor has a resolution of 1920x1080) and the size of my panel is 24

Comment: The max delay-time in 12.04 seems to be 10000 -- which is not enough for what we both want to do ;)