# Which is correct: "GNOME Classic" or "GNOME Fallback"?

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, terminology, gnome-fallback

Since the availability of Unity and GNOME Shell, I have noticed widespread confusion over whether the more "traditional" version of the GNOME desktop environment should be referred to as "GNOME Classic" or "GNOME Fallback" in 11.04, 11.10 and later.

What is the correct terminology to use? Also, does it differ by Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The classic GNOME 2 interface present in Ubuntu up to 11.04 but not in later releases is just GNOME 2 (with the default shell). The name of the *session type* for this interface was `Ubuntu Classic`, and the name of the session type for Unity was (and still is) `Ubuntu`, but that shouldn't be confused with the name of the interface itself--Ubuntu is an operating system, after all, not an interface.

Nonetheless, since any mention of "GNOME shell" evokes the idea of GNOME 3, and since Unity is also a GNOME interface, it is helpful to be able to characterize the classic GNOME 2 interface as separate both from any GNOME 3 interface and from versions of the Unity interface that used GNOME 2. Thus it's become almost common to call it GNOME Classic.

We should avoid calling it that, because that's capitalized and thus a proper name, and yet that is not the official name for it. In my opinion, we should instead say "the classic GNOME 2 interface."

The practical reason why it is bad to call the classic GNOME 2 interface "GNOME Classic" is that `GNOME Classic` is the name of the *session type* in Ubuntu 11.10 (and future versions) that provides the GNOME Fallback interface. The GNOME Fallback interface is a GNOME 3 interface that is designed to look and behave a lot (though not entirely) like the classic GNOME 2 interface.

Here's a condensed list of some interfaces and the session types that provide them in Ubuntu 11.04 and Ubuntu 11.10:

- The **Unity** interface (sometimes colloquially known as Unity 3D or 3D Unity, as it uses 3D graphics acceleration) is provided by the `Ubuntu` session type. The overarching desktop environment is *GNOME 2* in Ubuntu 11.04 and earlier versions, and *GNOME 3* starting with Ubuntu 11.10. The window manager has been `compiz` for a while. Install this with the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.
- The **Unity 2D** interface is provided by the `Ubuntu 2D` session type. The overarching desktop environment is *GNOME 2* in Ubuntu 11.04 and earlier versions (but `unity-2d` was only available by PPA back then), and *GNOME 3* starting with Ubuntu 11.10. The window manager is `metacity`. Starting with Ubuntu 11.04, install this with the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.
- The **classic GNOME 2** interface was provided by the `Ubuntu Classic` and `Ubuntu Classic (no effects)` session types. The overarching desktop environment was *GNOME 2*. This could be installed by the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.
- The **GNOME Fallback** interface (which is a GNOME 3 interface that looks like classic GNOME 2) is provided by the `GNOME Classic` and `GNOME Classic (no effects)` session types. The overarching desktop environment is *GNOME 3*. The window manager is `metacity`. Install this with the `gnome-session-fallback` package.
- The **GNOME 3** (or **GNOME 3 Shell** or **GNOME Shell**) interface is provided by the `GNOME` session type, starting in Ubuntu 11.10. (In significantly older versions of Ubuntu, the "GNOME" session type had once meant what the "Ubuntu Classic" session type means in Ubuntu 11.04.) The overarching desktop environment is *GNOME 3*. The window manager is `mutter`. Install this with the `gnome-shell` package.
- The **KDE 4** (or **KDE 4 Plasma**, or **KDE 4 Plasma Workspaces**, or just **KDE**) interface is provided by the `Kubuntu` session type. (Considerably over versions of Ubuntu had major version 3 of KDE instead.) The overarching desktop environment is *KDE 4* (frequently just called *KDE* these days, as it came out some time ago). The window manager is `kwin` (available via the traditional `kde-window-manager` package and, [as of Ubuntu 11.10, also available](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/11.10-release) in `kde-window-manager-gles`). Install this with the `kubuntu-desktop` metapackage.
- The **Xfce 4** (or **Xfce**) interface is provided by the `Xubuntu` session type. The overarching desktop environment is *Xfce 4* (also *Xfce4* or just *Xfce*). The window manager is `xfwm4`. Install this with the `xubuntu-desktop` metapackage.
- The **LXDE** interface is provided by the `Lubuntu` session type; it is also provided with a different configuration by the `Lubuntu Netbook` session type (this can arguably be considered a different interface). The overarching desktop environment is *LXDE*. The window manager is `openbox`. Install this with the `lubuntu-desktop` metapackage.

Comment: `GnomeShell` uses `mutter` as window manager and not `compiz`. But a well-explained opinion :)

Comment: @sagarchalise [So it does!](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/09/gnome-shell-in-ubuntu-1110-first.html) Fixed. Thanks! Btw, was `mutter` the window manager used for Unity prior to Ubuntu 11.04? (That rings a bell...)

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes `mutter` was used in the now extinct Netbook Version with the first Unity.

Comment: And Unity 2D is based on Gnome? wasn't it QT?

Comment: @UriHerrera The **Unity 2D** *interface* (that is, the *interface* provided in the `Ubuntu 2D` session type) is a GNOME interface, yes. Unity 2D itself is written using the Qt toolkit, which is the same toolkit that underlies the **KDE 4** *interface* and *desktop environment*. Qt4, like GTK+3, are toolkits, not interfaces or DE's. When you use **Unity 2D** as your interface, other parts of it are still certainly GNOME. The desktop and file browser are provided by Nautilus, for example. Similarly, Unity uses the Nux toolkit, but the overall interface wheh you use Unity is still GNOME.

Comment: @UriHerrera Arguably it would be better not to use the terms "Unity" and "Unity 2D" to refer to interfaces, just as it would be better not to use the term "GNOME Shell" to refer to an interface. These are shells for GNOME, rather than interfaces. But that's not the way most people speak. I think it's already entrenched virtually 100% that "Unity" is considered an appropriate answer to "What interface do you use in Ubuntu?"

Comment: @EliahKagan yeah i meant if Unity 2D was written in GTK and not QT  but wouldn't let me edit it. of course everything else is Gnome, but i did mean Unity 2D as the UI only.

Comment: Under 12.04 Gnome Classic uses compiz and Gnome Classic (no effects) uses metacity - but you can enable metacity compositing effects in Gnome Classic (no effects) using gconf-editor.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Would you mind adding `gnome-flashback` to this list? It's really confusing everything as well. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

gnome fallback(or flashback) is a gnome-panel interface,although gnome classic is gnome shell with a few extentions to make it more tradional.if you are looking forward to custumize your classic interface(especially the panel),you should have fallback but if you want it to stay the same use gnome classic.in gnome fallback the upperright corner is always "Applications Places"although in gnome classic it appends the focused app(Applications Places Files). i persnolly think fallback(now named flashback)is better,but you should try both