# What Is Gnome, Gnome Classic and Gnome Classic(No Effects)?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, gnome-classic

I am using ubuntu 12.04 lts and I was using unity 2D and i wanted to switch to unity 3D so i logged out and clicked on the ubuntu sign and there were 3 new options:

1 GNOME
2 GNOME CLASSIC and
3 Gnome CLASSIC (NO EFFECTS)

I started with all of the three one by one and I liked them but I dont what they are and how did i get them

can anyone tell me what they are?

Here is a screenshot of my desktop:[image]

Comment: Did you ever install something like `gnome-desktop`?

Comment: I dont remember.  I think not

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation:

- Gnome is Gnome version 3
- Gnome Classic is Gnome version 2
- Gnome Classic (No Effects) is version 2 but suited for less graphical VGAs

A usefull answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83351/which-is-correct-gnome-classic-or-gnome-fallback)