# How can I make Ubuntu look like Debian 6.0 "Squeeze"?

Tags: themes, customization, debian, desktop-environments

I really like [the simple look of Debian's interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX9gR.png). What desktop environment is it? Is it easy to replicate?

Answer (score 5):

That screenshot is gnome 2 on Debian and although you can make Ubuntu look somewhat like gnome 2, you can not run gnome 2 on Ubuntu.

You might be interested in an alternate window manager such as xubuntu or lubuntu (or Fluxbox)

Xubuntu

[image: Xubuntu]

Lubuntu

[image: Lubuntu]

Answer (score 4):

Debian 6 (squeeze) released in Oct '11 uses the older (more stable) GTK2 libraries and thus the Gnome 2 interface.

Ubuntu 11.10 and newer uses the GTk3 libraries - the older Gnome 2 interface is not directly available.

There are some similar questions and answers you could consider.

1. Customise Gnome-Fallback to look something similar to the older Gnome2 interface - so called [Gnome-Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)
2. Look at the [MATE Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate-in-11-10-and-above) which you could install as a desktop option in Ubuntu 11.10.
3. Brand new, just out is the [Cinnamon desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop) (and unstable)

Comment: There is also "How to Customize Gnome Classic Panel". http://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 you can install the Debian form of Gnome. You get by default Gnome 3, but you can choose to sign in not on Gnome, but on Gnome Classic, that is actually Gnome 2. You can do this on Ubuntu Server, not regular Ubuntu, but it is the same kernel, the same OS on the base. You install Ubuntu Server and make sure you are connected to the web. On first login, run the commands ”sudo apt-get update” and ”sudo apt-get upgrade”, to make sure all available updates are installed. After installation, reboot. Then run the command ”sudo apt-get install gnome”. After completion (it will take some time), reboot and you have an Ubuntu with Debian Gnome GUI. Just near the sign in button, you have an option menu, ”Gnome” is Gnome 3,and ”Gnome Classic” is Gnome 2. Make sure you download the  Ubuntu server iso, not other version.

Answer (score -1):

Debian uses gnome 2.x ubuntu has an option to log in gnome 2.
Just install the package below
http://packages.debian.org/sid/gnome-themes-standard

Comment: It appears that package only supplies the standard GNOME themes, and at any rate it is usually better to install a package directly from Ubuntu's repositories using `apt-get` or the Software Center.