# How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?

Tags: software-installation, cinnamon

I have read that there is a new Gnome-2 like interface called Cinnamon produced by the Linux Mint developers.

Is this available for Ubuntu users - and if so how do I install it?

Comment: The "Cinnamon Stable" PPA at https://launchpad.net/~embrosyn/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon appears to be maintained and allows Cinnamon 2.8 to be installed on 14.04 and 15.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Installing Cinnamon from an existing Environment

For what I've tested since I use the Cinnamon interface, the best way these days to install Cinnamon desktop is in my case on Ubuntu Mate.

There's no need need to add the ppa, because [Cinnamon packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cinnamon) (see link for version depending on Ubuntu release) are included on the Ubuntu sources.

Content description of every Cinnamon packages can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=cinnamon).

After a clean Ubuntu installation:

1. `sudo su`
2. `apt update && apt upgrade`
3. `apt install cinnamon`

---

If you like to install it minimaly (without any tools):

1. `apt install cinnamon --no-install-recommends`
2. `apt install -f` (to check for depencies)

---

4. `reboot`
5. Select the wanted default user interface before login

---

### Installing Cinnamon on Ubuntu server 22.04

**From scratch with no environement installed yet:**

If you would like to have the Ubuntu kernel with Cinnamon as **only** desktop environement:

1. You can download and install [Ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server)
2. Select the minimized installation and **no third party driver** *(because it will install a server version)*

[image: minimized-install]

4. update & upgrade & reboot after connection to your session instance.

   `sudo su`

   `apt update && apt upgrade`

   `reboot`
5. Install [muffin](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/muffin) *(low gnome window manager, where Cinnamon is based on)*

   `sudo apt install muffin`
6. Install [slick-greeter](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/slick-greeter.1.html) *(low gtk greeter made for muffin and looks like unity)*

   `sudo apt install slick-greeter`
7. And finally install the desktop environement (minimaly to get only the environment without other software):

   `sudo apt install cinnamon --no-install-recommends`
8. Install yaru-theme-icon package present on the Ubuntu server *(compatible icon pack as base)*

   `sudo apt install yaru-theme-icon`
9. Install your [graphic driver](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) and Reboot
10. resolve [networking applet issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135755/network-manager-applet-shows-not-connected-and-one-unmanaged-wired-connection/1439162)
11. Install additional packages to personalize your desktop.

I personally recommend gnome software since it's compatible with Ubuntu as much as with Cinnamon.

Even for system settings, like the control panel. I did install it for system management and testing, so here some I've installed:

```
sudo apt install gnome-logs eog inetutils-ping nmcli gnome-calculator gnome-screenshot xdg-user-dirs-gtk gedit-plugins gnome-font-viewer mate-themes simple-scan gparted gpart gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility
```

[You'll find more information about those on the Ubuntu packages page.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

For the greeter settings you'll need to install the "Login Window" settings: `sudo apt install lightdm-settings`

[image: Login Window settings]

For its background image use only the `/usr/share/backgrounds` folder. Because the user folder's aren't permitted.

For the internet browser, I prefer Chrome and install it with `wget` and `dpkg -i`.

Here's a screenshot of this desktop:
[image: my cinnamon desktop]

Here's the Cinnamon menu with usefull settings and tools configured into the "System Tools" menu for my needs.
[image: cinnamon menu]

Here's the greeter:
[image: greeter]

And here you can see no other environment choice as Cinnamon:
[image: select-environement]

**Last installation system information:**

Kernel: 5.19.0-23-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A

Desktop: Cinnamon v: 5.4.12

tk: GTK v: 3.24.34 dm: LightDM Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)

### Installing Cinnamon from Mint PPA on Ubuntu 22.04 server

In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450586/uninstalled-applications-arent-automatically-removed-from-the-cinnamon-menu/1451588#1451588) you can find how to install the most recent version of Cinnamon on your server, based on the Linux Mint PPA.

I've also a made a bash script menu to solve most of the issues I've got on Ubuntu server with Cinnamon installed. It's availble on Github [here](https://github.com/wingarmac/Bash-installer-menu).

[image: Bash-installer-menu]

[Related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450586/uninstalled-applications-arent-automatically-removed-from-the-cinnamon-menu/1451588#1451588)

Comment: There's a problem with the audio on Ubuntu 22.10 after install and dist-upgrade. I tested both. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipewire/+bug/1975823 - I don't know if it's related with the use of Cinnamon.

Comment: There's an issue with the `slick-greeter` configuration confusing `unity-greeter` and `lightdm-greeter` when tried setting it up with `lightdm-settings` or `lightdm-gtk-settings`. The background doesn't change and the accessibility options do not work. I'm still trying to set it up with GUI, but only `sudo -i` did work or editing configuration files manually.

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440796/how-to-setup-and-customise-ubuntu-cinnamons-slick-greeter-in-a-gui-menu

Comment: Network applet not showing connection: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135755/network-manager-applet-shows-not-connected-and-one-unmanaged-wired-connection/1439162#1439162

Comment: Solution found to sound problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436904/problem-with-sound-in-ubuntu-22-10/1440458#1440458

Comment: In my last installs with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I didn't had to install lightdm-settings, because the login options were already available in the Cinnamon settings (bottom of settings window) and it responded like a charm.

Comment: You need to be root to add wallpapers into the right folders in order these can be used for the login screen settings. No user folders are allowed.

Answer (score 121):

Cinnamon is a Gnome-Shell desktop fork.  It is not strictly a Gnome-2 interface, although the developers aims are laudable - to produce a simpler more traditional desktop interface.

Development seems to be rapid.  It is usable and certainly fun to play with with a growing number of extensions to install to extend the base installation.

### How to install

#### for 13.04 & 13.10, 14.10 & later

Cinnamon is now available in the Universe repository

[cinnamon [image: Install cinnamon]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cinnamon)

Alternatively - from the command-line:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

Since it is in this repository, it is community maintained and thus it is up to the community to update  the packages as and when new releases and bug-fixes are released.

For Ubuntu 14.04, there is currently no cinnamon packages in the Universe repository.

#### Via PPA for 11.10 and later

**EDIT: 22/05/2014 - the PPA `ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable` has been removed or hidden from public view.**  I contacted the maintainer and the following is their reply:

> The stable PPA is indeed no longer being maintained.
>
> The nightly PPA is being kept for development purposes and should not
>   be used on any sort of production machine (it can and will break at
>   any time).
>
> To be honest, I don't have an alternative to offer Ubuntu users at the
>   moment, apart from switching to a distribution that does support
>   Cinnamon. There are many such distributions out there, and I'm only
>   hoping for someone to (finally) step up on Ubuntu's side to provide
>   proper packages to its users.

EDIT: 25/04/14 - Two alternative PPA's have now been created - both claiming to enable the *stable* version of Cinnamon for Ubuntu users.  I cannot vouch for the [veracity of these PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)

**Option 1: 12.04 & 14.04 users only:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

**Option 2: 14.04 users only:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

As an alternative you may wish to consider the unstable nightly automatic builds - please note Gwendal's warning above:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

**Option 3:** In addition, you can also install cinnamon 2.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and derivatives by adding Linux Mint 17 Qiana  repository in your system.

Open file `/etc/apt/sources.list` with nano command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line at the end of file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana main upstream import
```

Update the repository then install the authentication key

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring
```

Update the repository again and install Cinnamon 2.2:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

#### After installation

Logout and select the Cinnamon session:

[image]

Enter you password and you'll see the Cinnamon desktop

[image]

... showing the traditional *start* type menu and applet design from Gnome-2

[image]

---

## Extensions/Applets

The Cinnamon desktop uses the same philosophy as Gnome-Shell - functionality can be added to by installing Extensions & Applets.

Cinnamon uses its own Settings tool.

*Cinnamon Settings*

[image]

*Cinnamon Applets*

Similar to gnome-shell extensions - you can install applets from a dedicated Mint website.

[image]

Comment: This was awesomely helpful would just like to add here that purge cinnamon does remove the packages but since the ppa is already added apt update events will pick up cinnamon packages to download and update ... To remove ppa 
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly

Comment: What saved me was the dedicated Mint website. Thank you so much !

Comment: It would be helpful if this could be updated, since it's now 2015 and Cinnamon is at version 2.6. There are descriptions on the Internet about using the PPA at `ppa:moorkai/cinnamon` for 15.04, but as far as I can tell that's not working due to a broken dependency on `libcjs0`.

Comment: @Pointy - cinnamon is available in the universe repo thus the answer still applies.  As for 15.04 + cinnamon v2.6 you should contact moorkai to see if the author will fix the PPA issue.  Once done we can add a "latest version " section for the answer.

Comment: @fossfreedom OK thanks. There's a "nightly" PPA too, but the version I installed from there is clearly broken (or there's some huge dependency problem, or whatever).  I'll contact moorkai.

Comment: Is it recommended to remove the former Desktop Environment after installing a new one, or does it make none to little difference?

Answer (score 18):

### 12.04 vs 11.10

I contacted the Ubuntu Cinnamon [PPA owner](https://launchpad.net/%7Egwendal-lebihan-dev) - Gwendal LE BIHAN - 2nd April - this is the reply:

> We are currently in the process of finalizing the migration of
> cinnamon to gnome3.4. The PPA will be updated with precise packages as
> soon as this is done.
>
> Those packages should be available within a week or 2, and definitely
> before precise's release.
>
> Note that no more releases of cinnamon will be available for other
> versions of Ubuntu, since the gnome3.4 libraries are not available on
> versions of Ubuntu prior to precise.

---

Precise builds are now available [in the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/94202/14356) and can be installed per the linked answer.

From now on, the Oneiric packages in the PPA will be fixed at v1.4.  Thus if you are an Oneiric (11.10) user, your upgrade route should be via the 12.04 distro route, followed by reactivating or adding the PPA.

Alternatively, you may wish to consider one of the other answers to the question.

Answer (score 10):

**PPA for 12.04 (nightly build)**

Packages for Precise are now available on the [nightly PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-nightly) :

The stable PPA will take a little more time before it gets updated, any feedback about the nightly packages will be very welcome.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Answer (score 5):

You can download [deb](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/downloads) files from [cinnamon github](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon) repository as well

Or you can directly use [linux mint repository](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Lisa). Just add to your software sources

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ lisa main
```

and do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring cinnamon cinnamon-session
```

Comment: That's now a bit outdated, but anyway, I tried `rebecca main` on 14.10 - unmet dependencies.

Comment: This should work with versions up to 14.04 (with `qiana` or `rebecca` for 14.04, and `maya` for 12.04). No Linux mint version are currently based on 14.10+, so this won't work for those releases - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases#Release_history) for how Mint and Ubuntu releases are related.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited on Oct- 25- 2015**

To install **Cinnamon 2.6** stable

Open terminal and run the following commands:

In **Ubuntu 15.04** Vivid

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moorkai/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

To install on **14.04 , 15.04 , 15.10**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kranich/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Answer (score 3):

For **15.10**:

After you enable the universe repository, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

Current version is 2.6.2

Answer (score 2):

**You can install Cinnamon 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS via PPA.**

Cinnamon 3.0 has been [released](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2016/04/cinnamon-3-0-released/) in April 2016 with improved GTK+ 3.20 support, new accessibility and sound settings and more. Although Cinnamon 3.0 is not available to install on Ubuntu through its official PPA you can install it by adding a [community PPA](https://launchpad.net/~embrosyn/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon). So use it at your own risk.

Before installing Cinnamon 3.0 on your Ubuntu 16.04, please purge [this PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) if you are already using it.

Use the following commands to install Cinnamon 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cinnamon blueberry
```

After the installation is finished log out and you can select Cinnamon desktop environment by clicking the icon next to your username.

[image]