# Error installing cinnamon desktop package

Tags: 11.10, apt, package-management, installation

Saw this article at howtogeek.com for [cinnamon desktop alternative](http://www.howtogeek.com/103691/install-linux-mints-new-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=270112).

Per the article, I successfully added the repository to ubuntu 11.10:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa

But then got these error messages when I try to install with:

> sudo apt-get install cinnamon cinnamon-session cinnamon-settings

I get these faults:

```
E: Unable to locate package cinnamon`
E: Unable to locate package cinnamon-session
E: Unable to locate package cinnamon-settings
```

Any suggestions to help resolve? Thanks!

Comment: Per Bruno's request:
 
I did execute, "sudo apt-get update", but got this error message: "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." Perhaps that's my problem. Any idea how to go about fixing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `sudo apt-get update` to update your sources list, if you did that please include that step in your question, without it it wont work.

The steps to use an additional source is:

1. Add the source
2. Update your lists with `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install packages with `sudo apt-get install foo1 foo2 foo3`

I have looked at that PPA and `cinnamon-session cinnamon-settings` packages do not exist, `cinnamon` is the only one you need to install.

---

Linked AskUbuntu! question:

1. [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

Comment: I did execute, "sudo apt-get update", but got this error message:
"E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."


Perhaps that's my problem.  Any idea how to go about fixing that?  Thanks!

Comment: @T.GregO'Neil I have tested the PPA, 2 packages do not exist, only `cinnamon` does. Try to only add `cinammon`. Btw the PPA is not down so the fault you get when you try `sudo apt-get update` is not caused this PPA, you have to check which is failing to download from the list shown during the update (404 error).

Comment: Bingo!  That did it.  The mozillateam ppa was causing the warnings that prevented the update from taking place.
THANKS BRUNO!