# Unmet dependency error while installing Cinnamon

Tags: apt, cinnamon

I added the required PPA for Cinnamon. Now when I run `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`, I get the unmet dependencies error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinnamon : Depends: gir1.2-muffin-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcogl5 (>= 1.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libmuffin0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's telling you right there what's wrong.. unmet dependencies

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

Comment: how do i resolve the unmet dependencies?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` ? If not, give it a try and then try installing cinnamon again.

Comment: yes... i did that...

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install cinnamon muffin` instead.  That used to be the way to install it, might still be true for 11.10 (versus 12.04).

Comment: "The" required PPA?  There's actually more than one floating around... one has been decreed the more "official" one however.  So which PPA are you using?  The more "official" one has combined, as I recall from the last time trying `cinnamon`, the `cinnamon` and `muffin` packages, so I'm wondering a bit.

Comment: actually... i added all the ppas which i found on the net... even the official one from their site...

Comment: sudo apt-get install cinnamon muffin also gives the same error

Comment: Use the following PPA: https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable updated 3-14

Comment: i have tried that ppa too :(

Comment: Using different ppas for the same program will likely damage your system. Try to remove all PPAs and then add BlueXrider one.

Comment: how do i remove ppas?

Comment: @gforce89 see this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/310/43660).

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh: Better use the most upvoted answer http://askubuntu.com/a/313/211.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, these commands work fine to fix the error:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome3-team-gnome3-oneiric.list* merlwiz79-cinnamon-ppa-oneiric.list* ricotz-testing-oneiric.list*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge gnome-desktop3-data
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Comment: @gforce89 Did this work?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Very bad idea.  Cinnamon *needs* muffin.

Comment: that doesnot work