# How can I uninstall Unity in 12.04 and install Cinnamon?

Tags: unity, 12.04, cinnamon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

I decided to install Cinnamon, as it's by far superior than Unity in my opinion.

However, I don't know from where to install it.

Comment: I've sent a question to the PPA owner as per this Q&A (http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop) - if i get a reply I'll drop an answer for you.  thanks.