# Updating and supporting the use of the Cinnamon Desktop

Tags: cinnamon

I have been reading this Q&A:

[How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

It looks like something I might be interested in.  However, I have some concerns about support - that is software updates and how they impact using this desktop.

I'm trying to understand how this is to be supported.

Will the community or Canonical provide support this or at least provide updates for it through the official repositories  - especially since 12.04 is a LTS release?

My concerns are what could happen when I use Update Manager to get the latest software and possible impacts.  Hopefully someone can guide me through this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cinnamon is not developed for Debian or Ubuntu in mind but rather for Linux Mint. As such, it is not in Debian repositories or Ubuntu repositories. Because of this, there is no specific reason for Canonical or the community to provide support or any updates for it.

If you are looking for updates, you have to use the PPA you have found in the linked question.

- [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

- What do you mean by that can you give more information.
- Canonical wont provide support or updates for that you will need to
  add an official repo to it see the install tutorial [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/103691/install-linux-mints-new-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu/)
- No as in #3 you can see we need to add an repo and then install it
- Yes , nearly any app that will work on ubuntu will work on it.