# How to install GNOME2 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

How can I install GNOME2 desktop on Ubuntu 11.10? I really **hate** Unity desktop in Ubuntu 11.10! Unity desktop is **absolutely** terrible! What terrible design! The classification is **absolutely** terrible! I really want to install GNOME2 on Ubuntu 11.10. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm closing this since other similar "gnome 2" questions have been asked in the past and the above duplicate link is the response given.  Thanks.

Comment: Gnome Classic != Gnome2

Answer (score 1):

Go to software center and install the gnome package.
[image: Gnome package in ubuntu software center]
Then, when you log in, in the right above of your pasword box there's a icon of ubuntu.
Click and select gnome(classic) and you log in in the classic gnome desktop.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You Can't. GNOME2 is a dead project. But there are other options:

- [**MATE**](http://mate-desktop.org/)

The gnome2 fork backed by linux-mint as well. I think they have finally found the     way to install it side by side with gnome3.

[Here is the installation instruction with much more about mate recent developments and features.](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/mate-desktop-12-released-install-it-in.html)

- **Gnome3 fallbak session**

Much more info here [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

[Blog-Post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed/) about how it looks

- [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/)

Linux Mints own answer to unity/gnome-shell woes.

[How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

- [XFCE](http://xfce.org)

Already known for its lightweightness, it has a plugin to run some gnome-applets and is not moving to gtk3 for next release. Although not the same but give similar interface.

Here are some more DE for ubuntu . See if some may fit your need   [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-des-and-shells-are-available)