# How to get MGSE under Gnome 3.4? (Or how to go from Gnome 3.4 to Gnome 3.2?)

Tags: gnome, command-line, compatibility, gnome-shell-extension

I just upgraded from Oneiric to Ubuntu 12.04.
I also installed Gnome shell 3.4, the only problem with it is that I can't use my favourite shell extensions (MGSE).
Does anyone know a way I could still get Gnome 3.2 or how to get MGSE on Gnome 3.4?

Your Help would be appreciated

Comment: Just so you know.. the Mint extensions are for Gnome 3.2, and they don't work in Gnome 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

The MGSE (Mint Gnome Shell Extensions) are a part of Liunx Mint, and the Cinnamon desktop  to be the default in Mint 13. Development of MGSE perhaps has stopped, bat Cinnamon provide s the same interface. Cinnamon is a fork of Gnome Shell, and is optional desktop for Ubuntu (and any distro for that matter). If you like install it in Ubuntu.

[How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

`mgse-menu` has been adapted into a gnome shell extension for Gnome 3.4, named [Axe Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/327/axe-menu/). Also, it adds lots of configuration options in the right click menu.