# How to remove Lubuntu desktop environment and go back to default again?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, restore, default, unity-greeter

I have problem with Ubuntu. It is always starting with the low graphic settings and it is running slowly.

1. I installed the Lubuntu desktop environment and then I realized that I didn't like it, so I tried to remove it. I probably set SeatDefaults to blank or:

   ```
   user-session=ubuntu

   greeter-session=unity-greeter
   ```
2. How do I set it back to Ubuntu? I don't remember all the changes I made and I am unsure of how to fix them. I don't want to lose my apps or documents.

Edit: After running code suggested by Nathan Smith I get these outputs

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove abiword abiword-commonabiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview  ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data blueman  chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg  elementary-icon-theme esound-common galculator gdebi gdebi-core  gecko-mediaplayer giblib1 gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools  gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview  gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo indicator-status-provider-pidgin leafpad  libaacs0 libabiword-2.9 libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libaudiofile1 libbinio1ldbl  libbluray1 libbs2b0 libcddb2 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libencode-locale-perl  libept1.4.12 libesd0 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers  libfile-listing-perl libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk1 libfm1  libfont-afm-perl libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgmlib0  libgmtk0 libgmtk0-data libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgringotts2  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtkmathview0c2a libguess1 libhtml-form-perl  libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl  libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libimlib2 libio-socket-inet6-perl  libio-socket-ssl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs liblink-grammar4  libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl  libmailtools-perl libmcrypt4 libmenu-cache1 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0  libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libobrender27 libobt0  libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libresid-builder0c2a  libsidplay2 libsocket6-perl libtar0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl  libtimedate-perl libuniconf4.6 liburi-perl libvdpau1 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-4  libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl  libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfconf-0-2  libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1  lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lubuntu-artwork  lubuntu-artwork-12-04 lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop  lubuntu-icon-theme lubuntu-software-center lxappearance lxappearance-obconf  lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin  lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer2 mtpaint  ntp obconf openbox openbox-themes osmo pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data  pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo  plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text python-pysqlite2 python-xklavier scrot sylpheed  sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends  transmission ttf-lyx uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn  xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf  xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-dat
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Package 'indicator-status-provider-pidgin' is not installed, so not                       removed
 Package 'libfm1' is not installed, so not removed
 Package 'libmenu-cache1' is not installed, so not removed
 Package 'libxfce4util4' is not installed, so not removed
 E: Unable to locate package abiword-commonabiword-plugin-grammar
 E: Unable to locate package libabiword-2.9
 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libabiword-2.9'
 E: Unable to locate package libfm-gtk1
 E: Unable to locate package libgmlib0
 E: Unable to locate package libgmtk0
 E: Unable to locate package libgmtk0-data
 E: Unable to locate package libobrender27
 E: Unable to locate package libobt0
 E: Unable to locate package openbox-themes
```

Edit_2/Update:

After running code suggested code from Nathan Smith:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove abiword abiword-plugin-mathview ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data blueman chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg elementary-icon-theme esound-common galculator gdebi gdebi-core gecko-mediaplayer giblib1 gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo leafpad libaacs0 libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libaudiofile1 libbinio1ldbl libbluray1 libbs2b0 libcddb2 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libencode-locale-perl libept1.4.12 libesd0 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfile-listing-perl libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfont-afm-perl libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgringotts2 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtkmathview0c2a libguess1 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libimlib2 libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmcrypt4 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libresid-builder0c2a libsidplay2 libsocket6-perl libtar0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libuniconf4.6 liburi-perl libvdpau1 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-4 libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1 lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-artwork-12-04 lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-icon-theme lubuntu-software-center lxappearance lxappearance-obconf lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer2 mtpaint ntp obconf openbox osmo pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text python-pysqlite2 python-xklavier scrot sylpheed sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends transmission ttf-lyx uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-data
```

It proccess with no problems but then when I reboot I am stuck on booting screen of Ubuntu.

My next question is if I can restore the whole system to default with loosing everything but I will start from scratch without needing USB,CD,DVD or other bootable media to boot the system from?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you've switched to Ubuntu, but the computer can't handle it. Can you post some hardware specs: CPU, RAM, graphics card (the graphics is most important).

Comment: It is my old compaq nx6110 which was bringed back to life week ago. It has Intel celeron M 1.50GHZ,Intel 915GM x86/MMX/SSE2,OS 32bit, Disk 156,1GB. Before it was running very well.

Comment: Lubuntu is a good choice for an old machine, Ubuntu, ...not so much.

Comment: Its good choice but I like the look of Ubuntu :) before it, it was running pretty good compare to when it has windows on it

Comment: The OP has made it fairly clear he doesn't want to use Lubuntu because he doesn't like the interface.  Also, you guys do realise that Lubuntu is not a separate OS to Ubuntu, right?

Comment: drkokandy do you read the whole problem I posted here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the steps outlined in the answer to the question [how-to-delete-all-desktop-environments-except-unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181356/how-to-delete-all-desktop-environments-except-unity), skipping the other desktop environments besides lubuntu-desktop that they're  removing.  (They'd also installed xubuntu, cinnamon, & gnome)

EDIT: Here, try it now. I threw together a quick python script to remove the packages that came up in the errors from the original command. It gave me:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove abiword abiword-plugin-mathview ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data blueman chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg elementary-icon-theme esound-common galculator gdebi gdebi-core gecko-mediaplayer giblib1 gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo leafpad libaacs0 libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libaudiofile1 libbinio1ldbl libbluray1 libbs2b0 libcddb2 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libencode-locale-perl libept1.4.12 libesd0 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfile-listing-perl libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfont-afm-perl libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgringotts2 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtkmathview0c2a libguess1 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libimlib2 libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmcrypt4 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libresid-builder0c2a libsidplay2 libsocket6-perl libtar0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libuniconf4.6 liburi-perl libvdpau1 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-4 libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1 lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-artwork-12-04 lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-icon-theme lubuntu-software-center lxappearance lxappearance-obconf lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer2 mtpaint ntp obconf openbox osmo pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text python-pysqlite2 python-xklavier scrot sylpheed sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends transmission ttf-lyx uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-data
```

And if that doesn't work, it might be enough if you just instead used

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove lubuntu-desktop
```

As mentioned there, after that command, you should also autoclean to toss out unneeded old package data, & update & dist-upgrade for updates w/ smart dependency handling as follows:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

UPDATE #2:
Try rebooting your computer, then instead of logging in normally, press Ctrl+Alt+F1. This should get you to the text-mode tty1 shell (Ctrl+Alt+F7 will get you back to GUI - once GUI is repaired!). Enter your username and password to log in.

If you're lucky, you'll have internet (to find out, type 'ping askubuntu.com' wait a couple sec & if you're getting responses other than error/timeout, it works & you can stop it w/ ctrl+c) otherwise you can do a search & find guides how to connect to the network from the command line.

Now you can probably try something along the lines of

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install unity unity-greeter
```

and reboot. Also, check out LightDM's display manager [documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/) & ubuntu-specific [documentation here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM). You may need to reinstall/reconfigure it to get things working

If that doesn't work, or if it seems harder than obtaining bootable media, then your best bet might be to try Xubuntu or whichever other Ubuntu version you think will work best. From the live session, you should be able to move your important files, then install. There are also ways to create a frugal install (like a live session on your main disk) sometimes w/o bootable media, but they can be tricky as you'll have to use a lot of command line utilities &/or get a virtual machine running.

Good luck!

Comment: I was following the recipe but it didn't work, adding console output in Edit

Comment: I edited my answer; give it a try now

Comment: I runned the script and it removes every app :D and now It is stuck on booting screen :D, At least I back up my docs :D