# Will installing Cinnamon break my settings?

Tags: gnome, cinnamon

I'm not sure the title is clear so I'll try to specify. I currently have Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome installed on it. I've done at least 16 hours of random tweaking and reading, mostly to give myself a better user experience.

I've installed and modified Sublime Text 2, installed a bunch of drivers, software, transferred files, etc. I want to know if I install Cinnamon and use it instead of Gnome, will it change my settings? For example, I have a "Show Desktop" keybinding set up (Super + D) that took me a while to figure out how to get working, will Cinnamon make me re-modify it?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the installation instructions here:

- [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

It looks like Cinnamon doesn't ship in Ubuntu, and since it's in a PPA:

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

So really the answer is "maybe?". You should certainly [back up your settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) before attempting that though.

Comment: How do I "back up my settings" in Linux?

Comment: That's another question. Please ask it separately **after checking** that it hasn't been asked and answered satisfactorily.