# Cinnamon themes don't show up in Cinnamon settings

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, cinnamon

I've been having an issue with trying to get a new theme working with Cinnamon. I installed Cinnamon using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

I've tried adding themes by adding creating a `.themes` folder in my home directory (and moving the extracted theme files there), as well as moving the new themes to `usr/share/themes` folder as well.

After attempting both of these solutions the only theme in Cinnamon setting is still "Cinnamon".

I've having this issue on both my desktop that is running 12.04 and my laptop that is running 12.10.

What could be causing this issue?
[image]

Comment: [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop/1438604#1438604) for help on installlation of Cinnamon on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that cinnamon but the following instruction works very well:

If you are using any Mint application (like your currnet cinnamon), remove that application and PPA from your system.

now install this one for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

my recommendation is to install mint themes to have a better experience:

```
sudo apt-get install mint-themes
```