# Remove Nautilus File Selector from the default

Tags: nautilus

How do I change the default file selector?

I already did this:

[Set Nemo as Default File Manager in Ubuntu](http://www.fandigital.com/2013/01/set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu.html)

But it doesn't work. Nautilus still is the default.

Comment: What things do you try and what do you expect to happen? For example, are you clicking the folder in the Unity side bar and it's opening Nautilus?

Comment: I recommend you to use Cinnamon Shell. Not only it looks far better than Unity, it is so easy to install a lot of beautiful themes, very easy user interface, and your best `Nemo` File manager is by default in it. Reply for further assistance.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 I want to upload images, but the preview on Natilus sucks. So I have to change the file-selector. But on firefox it remains the same.

Comment: I found this as the best link to illustrate how to install Cinnamon. http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop

Comment: Even with cinnamon the file-selector still is nautilus.