# Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cinnamon

Is it already possible to install cinnamon on new "trusty" Ubuntu? If yes, how?
I have tried to search it in official repos but without success and ppa that worked on 13.10

```
gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
```

doesn't work on 14.04, apt-get update gives

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: As with all PPA's - give the developers and maintainers sometime (few days/weeks) to update for the new releases - This will probably become a duplicate of this when the PPA is updated: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop

Comment: Just wait until the devs update their PPAs. There's nothing you can do.

Comment: Ok, understood :-)

Comment: you can add gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly but is pretty unstable and breaks quite often

Comment: See bottom of this page regarding the 2.2 nightly. This worked for me. http://linuxg.net/cinnamon-2-2-has-been-released-how-to-install-cinnamon-2-2-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

Comment: I tried adding the "nightly" PPA because it had support for trusty. It was wildly unstable, would often freeze, and when I removed it and tried to return to Unity, Unity was broken too.

Definitely not recommended.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/alternative-cinnamon-ppa-for-ubuntu.html) page, the gwendal-dev-lebihan/cinnamon-stable ppa is dead, (even saucy users can't access it, anymore). Only the nightly ppa is still accessible.