# Cinnamon PPA was not found

Tags: apt, ppa, cinnamon

I am unable to add Cinnamon PPA on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The add-apt-repository can't access the PPA. Also, when I visit PPA URL on https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable, I get 404 error. Is the Cinnamon PPA deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the PPA you are trying to add has been deleted. The first question on [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop) has an edit by the maintainer explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Mint application (like your currnet cinnamon), remove that application and PPA from your system.

now install this one for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

my recommendation is to install mint themes to have a better experience:

```
sudo apt-get install mint-themes
```