# How To Install Cinnamon on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, cinnamon

I've read some things in some forums however they usually tell me to add a PPA third, to update and run the command apt to install the cinnamon, but it never works. When running the command returns the terminal saying it is impossible to install due to lack of dependencies, and which I can not download and install individually. I've tried adding the repositories of Linux Mint to Ubuntu, nothing bad.

I wonder how to do that or compile the source code.

Comment: have you tried this question: [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop). Please add more information yo your question by [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/500373/edit)ing it - for instance, what command did you use to try and install cinnamon, and what errors resulted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the right way to install it has recently changed - so most directions you can find on the net will be outdated and no longer working for a while.

[Popular Cinnamon PPA for Ubuntu 14.04 To Close](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/ubuntu-cinnamon-desktop-ppa-retired)

The change is that the former "official" PPA has been closed. But there is a replacement now, see this duplicate question:

[How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)