# Getting Notification in Ubuntu 14.04 that "Update Information is Outdated"

Tags: 14.04, updates, cinnamon

Hoping someone can assist with this as I am for some reason getting this everytime I fire up my Ubuntu box.

I basically performed a "sudo apt-get update" and received the following info:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_AU                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 2,064 kB in 24s (85.8 kB/s)                                            
N: Ignoring file 'extra.list.backup' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I did have cinnamon installed but un-installed. Not sure if I missed something here.

Any help to remove these messages would be much appreciated.

FYI, I am running Unity.

Thanks.

**UPDATED**

Attempted to run A.B's commands below and received the following issues:

```
$sudo ppa-purge ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa
Updating packages lists
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
PPA to be removed: merlwiz79 cinnamon-ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: merlwiz79 cinnamon-ppa
```

Comment: That PPA is quite ancient and does not support 14.04 - reading [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/94201/178596) may help, or if you want to try cinnamon stable builds you could try the ones suggested [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/new-cinnamon-stable-ubuntu-ppas-ubuntu.html) (`ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon` for 12.04 & 14.04, `ppa:lestcape/cinnamon` for 14.04 only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the PPA `ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa`, as it doesn't contain any Trusty packages:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/merlwiz79-ubuntu-cinnamon-ppa-*.list
   ```

   The removal via `ppa-purge` doesn't work in this case, because there are no Trusty packages
2. Remove the file `extra.list.backup`:

   ```
   sudo rm extra.list.backup
   ```
3. Remove the entries `http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty main`:

   - Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
     ```
   - Search and remove the line `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty main`
4. Upgrade your system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Comment: A.B - pls see my update above after trying to run the command: sudo ppa-purge ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa

Comment: Open  up Software & Updates > Other.. & see if that ppa is listed. If so then highlight & click on Remove. Reload sources, ect

Comment: @tonsils Sorry, my mistake. :\

Comment: All good now and no probs A.B - appreciate your  help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and the solution is straightforward:
Just remove the offending ppas. They are found either in **/etc/apt/sources.list** as **lines** or in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/** as **files**.

Now the message will no longer occur on apt-get update ^^

Consider, though, that any packages depending on the just removed ppa (without alternative sources) will get no updates any more...