# Ubuntu 14.04 + Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I installed Cinnamon like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Also tried this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

All finished ok, but there was no result after reboot. Why?

Comment: Did you choose the cinnamon session when you logged in?

Comment: @terdon, there is no cinnamon session...

Comment: You really not provide any helpful information. Is difficult be a magician to know what really happen in an open problem like this. Please, start the Unity desktop. Open a terminal and execute "cinnamon --restart" without quote. If cinnamon can start, your problem will be related with your display manager (lightdm), if not you will get the error. With an error, we can have an idea of what is happened.

Comment: The [PPA in question](https://launchpad.net/~lestcape/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon) doesn't exist any longer. VTC as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

If you see no "Cinnamon" option after rebooting, that probably means you didn't install a cinnamon session. The simplest fix would probably be to install the full desktop environment:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

That will, however, bring in various other packages you might not want. I can't test this at the moment, but it might be enough to just install

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-session
```

The package names might be slightly different. To see what you have available, run

```
apt-cache search '^cinnamon'
```

Comment: I think it will help! Thx! But I googled for a repository with cinnamon-desktop-environment. But all of them had no cinnamon-desktop-environment. Could you give me a name of a good repository for this?

Comment: @ArthurKharkivskiy sorry, no idea, I don't use Ubuntu. Isn't it in the normal repos? If not, you could always use Mint's repo or just download the deb.

Comment: How about this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop  ?