# Repository with cinnamon-desktop-environment for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon

I need a repository with cinnamon-desktop-environment for Ubuntu. Googled, but all of them have no CDE.
P.S. No, answer about Mate is unuseful because of pure design.

```
arthur@arthur-pc:~$ apt-cache policy cinnamon cinnamon-common
cinnamon:
  Installed: 2.4.8
  Candidate: 2.6.8-20150622040006-trusty
  Version table:
     2.6.8-20150622040006-trusty 0
        700 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-    nightly/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.4.8 0
        700 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon/ubuntu/             trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.2.16 0
    500 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/main amd64 Packages
cinnamon-common:
  Installed: 2.4.8
  Candidate: 2.6.8-20150622040006-trusty
  Version table:
 2.6.8-20150622040006-trusty 0
        700 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.4.8 0
            700 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.16 0
            500 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: The package was introduced in 15.04, so it's unlikely you'll get in 14.04. Just install manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will I be able to get an interface that is like Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441360/will-i-be-able-to-get-an-interface-that-is-like-gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Check the official MATE wiki http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

Comment: Why do you need exactly this package?

Comment: @A.B., because of I have no Cinnamon session after the Cinnamon installation.

Comment: What's your login manager?

Comment: There you can select your session.

Comment: @ArthurKharkivskiy if you don't have a Cinnamon session, then ask about that, not about a package you think will solve your problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
 Which files are present in `/usr/share/xsessions` and, what is the output of `apt-cache policy cinnamon cinnamon-common`?

Comment: @muru, /usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon.desktop
/usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon2d.desktop.  Output in the question description.

Comment: but I have no Cinnamon in the login screen.

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic here, please ask on [unix.se].

Comment: @muru, a desktop environment and a distro is not the same. He don't use a different distro, so here or in launchpad will be the correct place to ask, but not in linux mint, as clear this is not a Mint problem. What is not ok is that he open two question for the same thing. http://askubuntu.com/questions/639537/ubuntu-14-04-cinnamon

Comment: @lestcape I know the difference between a desktop environment and a distro. I also know the Mint repositories when I see them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **ONE** of the PPAs below. Please **do not use both** PPAs simultaneously.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

### or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

---

You can remove Cinnamon with `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

And depending which PPA you have used:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon
```

or

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
```

Comment: Both contain a `cinnamon-desktop`, neither contains [`cinnamon-desktop-environment`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/cinnamon-desktop-environment). What's the difference?

Comment: @muru Ups, OP needs `cinnamon-desktop-environment`? I clarify that.