# Boot script issue after formatting computer

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, format

I am new to Linux, currently using Linux Mint. I enjoyed it so much that I decided to ditch Windows altogether. So I formatted my entire hard disk and installed Linux Mint.
I got a warning during the installation that I should install a EFI boot partition but I ignored it.
Upon reboot it couldn't locate the OS so I went into BIOS and switched from UEFI to Legacy.

I was finally able to boot Mint but upon hitting suspend, it crashed and said "Boot script table modified" and shut down.
I figured using "boot repair" would do the trick, so I tried to boot from my USB key but every time (even in UEFI mode) it goes to "(initramfs) prompts/busybox" and waits for an input. So I can't even get to the LIVE USB to run "boot repair".

I know I messed up really bad. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Sorry but Mint is off topic here, only official Ubuntu releases are supported, please ask at  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this might be a general question, it doesn't have to do with the specific OS. But okay, I'll ask there. Thanks.

Comment: It might be general, it might also be based on how you installed it (and therefore how Mint's installer works).

Comment: Do you think installing Ubuntu might fix the problem?

Comment: No one can say, you could just try it from a live USB and see how it goes, if it works you can install the cinnamon desktop, like on Mint, with this guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, go to your boot menu when starting your computer and change the option to Legacy Boot. This should fix the problem. This occurs while using Ubuntu also.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. As I mentioned "Upon reboot it couldn't locate the OS so I went into BIOS and switched from UEFI to Legacy." So this is how I was able to use my OS. However, that's not the issue.

The issue is using the Live USB tool in Mint, which I can no longer access. And the boot script table error.