# What's the difference between the apt packages: 'cinnamon' and 'cinnamon-desktop-environment'?

Tags: apt, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I have a fresh Ubuntu install and want to install Cinnamon as the desktop environment. When I do `apt search cinnamon`, I get multiple results, but two seems like they are the correct one.

The first is just

```
cinnamon/xenial 2.8.6-1ubuntu1 amd64 all
    Innovative and comfortable desktop (Common data files)
```

while the other is

```
cinnamon-desktop-environment/xenial,xenial 2.8.0 all
    Cinnamon desktop environment - full desktop with extra components
```

What's the difference between the two? What does the `cinnamon-desktop-environment` package contain that the `cinnamon` doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I cannot answer what is not included in `cinnamon` as opposed to `cinnamon-destop-environment`  I can answer your broader question.

`cinnamon-destop-enviroment` is a meta package.  A meta package does not include any real programs in it it is more of a recipe.  It directs the package manager to pull in all the needed programs for the desktop environment to  work fully and have all the features it should. It will pull in `cinnamon` and all the other files needed for a full Cinnamon Desktop install

Without it, just installing `cinnamon` would most likely get you a working desktop but features would be missing.  For example you could be missing the bluetooth manager for Cinnamon.  As some of this stuff would be installed in standard Ubuntu, you would likely have a functioning desktop but might have to do some stuff in terminal only because you are missign the graphical front-end in Cinnamon.  I will also make it much harder for you to get help because instruction for Cinnamon will not work because you are missing a program needed in the instructions.

In short you want to install the `cinnamon-desktop-enviroment`  to get the full desktop.  In doing so, however, you will have doubles of some programs.  Nautilus will still be installed but Cinnamons default Nemo will also be installed, so if you search for "files" you will come up with two programs with that name, you will need to search for Nemo.

---

One other word of warning, you may find it harder to get help here with Cinnamon installed, it is a minority DE so less people will be available to help you.  If you are just trying to get a Gnome2 like desktop, you might look at installing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and using the Gnome Classic desktop from the login screen, it looks and works like the old Gnome2 desktops.

Installing the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` will affect your Ubuntu Unity, especially the top bar.  Everything will still work in Unity but the icon will be a mix of Unity's default and Gnome's default icons.  Ubuntu Gnome in a official flavor of Ubuntu so is supported on these forums.  As you have a fresh install you could just reinstall Ubuntu Gnome instead of installing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`  but the result will be the same.

There is one bug with Ubuntu Gnome that affect Nautilus, it causes freezing in the menu. If you want to use Gnome, you could install another file manager, the closest would be Nemo(my preference, it's Nautilus with more features).  To do that there are a few step but they are easy, see  http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html for instructions.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed answer! Gnome Classic looks like a good alternative to Cinnamon. One question though. You say that since Cinnamon is a minority DE on here, it might be harder to find a solution to any problems. Why would that be?

Comment: To add a little to my previous comment, I've read some more about display managers. Since Cinnamon is a fork of GNOME, wouldn't a lot of what one would do to fix/troubleshoot GNOME apply to Cinnamon as well?

Comment: @eirik-ff  To answer your comments.  I said that Cinnamon is a minority DE because only a small number of people on these forums use it.  You could probably get help on the Mint forums but they are not as well organized as  Stack Exchange forums are so it is a lot harder to find what you are looking for.  2). Most answers for Gnome 2 should work for solutions but the Mint team has changed some code for compatibility and performance.  Some Gnome2 answers may not be relevant anymore and the gap will only get larger as time goes by and they make more changes to the code.

Comment: Content description of every [Cinnamon packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=cinnamon) can be found here

Comment: See here for help on [installation of Cinnamon on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop/1438604#1438604)

Answer (score 8):

Look at the output of:

```
apt show cinnamon cinnamon-desktop-environment cinnamon-core
```

Basically you can say that `cinnamon` is a part of `cinnamon-core` which itself is a part of `cinnamon-desktop-environment`.

- `cinnamon` is the most basic and minimal Cinnamon installation you can get.
- `cinnamon-core` is a minimal Cinnamon desktop, but it also includes few more packages than `cinnamon`, like the e.g. file manager `nemo`.
- `cinnamon-desktop-environment` is a full desktop environment suite which also includes standard applications like a browser, mail client, document viewer, editor, picture viewer, multimedia viewer, etc...