# Where is my cinnamon desktop

Tags: cinnamon

I downloaded Linux Mint 18.1 with (I thought) the cinnamon desktop. I received a set of files but no Cinnamon desktop and no terminal file so I can't enter the commands. How do I get the Cinnamon desktop on my USB?

Answer (score 0):

This site is about Ubuntu, not Linux Mint.

If you want to install the Cinnamon Desktop on Ubuntu, follow the instructions in [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/94201/425630).