# Network manager applet shows 'not connected', and one unmanaged Wired connection, internet working

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, cinnamon

I have no experience configuring network manager by text configs, used only GUI. When moving mouse over NM tray icon there are tooltip "Not connected", however I see one connection then clicking it - "Wired unmanaged". Internet working fine.
I make new ethernet connection with priority 10 but it not appear in NM applet menu.  [image: plugin menu] [image]

```
leonid@DevSSD:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown

leonid@DevSSD:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: true
            nameservers:
                addresses: [127.0.0.1,127.0.0.53]
                search: [JR]
```

Question is: how to connect by new created ethernet connection, or at least make "wired" connection managed?
Ubuntu 18.04 cinnamon

Comment: Change "managed=true" back to false, and edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @heynnema Question updated

Comment: Is this a desktop machine, or a server?

Comment: Desktop, with cinnamon, not gnome

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes to put together an answer. Did you already set back "managed=false"?

Comment: Yes, managed=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf back to:**

```
managed=false
```

**Set /etc/network/interfaces back to:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**Change /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:**

Rename 01-netcfg.yaml to 01-netcfg.yaml.HOLD for backup purposes.

`sudo mv /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml.HOLD`

Create a new file called /etc/netplan/config.yaml...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/config.yaml` # create/edit a new file

or

`sudo pico /etc/netplan/config.yaml` # create/edit a new file

with the following content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate` # generate new config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Use the standard NetworkManager menu to configure your "Wired Connection".

Verify Internet operation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 22.10 server with Unity based Cinnamon desktop.

I did as follow (based on @heynnema's answer):

- `/etc/network/interfaces` did not exist, so I created it with inside:

  `auto lo`

  `iface lo inet loopback`
- I did'nt found 01, but 00-netcfg.yaml instead in /etc/netplan/.

I just edited it as by adding **"renderer: NetworkManager"**:

*(other devices not used yet - only one is dchp for internet)*

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s4f0:
      dhcp4: false
    enp2s4f1:
      dhcp4: false
    enp3s6f0:
      dhcp4: false
    enp3s6f1:
      dhcp4: false
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

With as results for all of my devices after the `netplan apply` command:

[image: cinnamon-network-manager]