# Cinnamon on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, cinnamon

I want to install Cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (on Dell XPS 15, 4k, nvidia gtx1650ti + 2 external 1080p LCDs).
I read that i need to change GDM3 to LightDM as well.
Is there also a problem with Wayland vs Xorg ?

Any advices or warnings ? is it a good idea? or should i expect some problems ?

is it really just easy like here?  (and no problems) https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: The lightdm login screen (display manager) is not needed but you can use it if you want (the dependency calls for gdm or lightdm). If you do install lightdm you can switch display managers by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and then select gdm or lighdm and then reboot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

Comment: It was not not only installing but also about issues. for now i have few: 1. I need to use Cinnamon Software rendered to use my NVidia card (and as always i spent few hours figuring it out), 2. Cinnamon does not support monitors with different DPI (and different scaling)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is beneficial to use cinnamon instead of the default Ubuntu desktop because it uses less resources while providing all features (I personally liked it more than the default).

Simply run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

If you face any issues you can just switch back to your default desktop environment easily by clicking the gear icon at login screen.

Comment: Also not good to recommend installing another desktop unless you know it will work well.  Just because it can be done, does not mean we should.

Comment: here it looks quite straightforward ...
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: @crip659 According to the answer, `it uses less resources while providing all features (I personally liked it more than the default)` it sounds like it works well. Also, as the answer states, if you have any trouble, you can switch back to your default desktop. You don't have to reinstall the default, just log out and switch desktop environments on your login screen. No big deal. If you can, then why not?

Comment: @mchid  the OP is using gnome, not unity as the answer thought.  Installing some desktops to a system can sometimes make a mess.  Myself can recommend adding unity to a gnome system, but can't recommend another desktop since I do not know how they will behave together.

Comment: @crip659  I hear you, but Gnome means that Cinnamon even more compatible because Cinnamon (unlike Unity) is actually built on Gnome. The only desktop I've ever seen to cause conflicts is Kubuntu (and this was a long time ago) because of all the QT dependencies and settings. Cinnamon is GTK and built on Gnome so I see no conflict. Also, Lubuntu (gtk version), Ubuntustudio, Xubuntu, all run well together, although you might have to switch lightdm or GDM themes depending on your preference. I personally like the default `unity-greeter` lighdm theme or Gnome gdm3 theme over the others.

Comment: I recommended it because I myself using it in Ubuntu 18.04.4 and it is working very well.