# How to change menu font contrast in Gnome Classic?

Tags: fonts, menu, customization, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.04 gnome classic ambiance oneric](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131417/12-04-gnome-classic-ambiance-oneric)

I have problem with color of menu in Ubuntu 12.04 ([Gnome Classic](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed/)).

Look image:

[image]

In Gnome Classic (No effect) all is OK.

Sorry for english .

Answer (score 1):

The menu could be selected with Alt+Super+Rt. click. You go to Panel properties and could change the background colour and its opacity feature. By default the menu takes up the colour which you use in the theme.

Just go through the simple [steps shown here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel) and finish the rest.

Comment: Don't work, color under Applications and Place don't change, only uder icons.