# Ambience theme error on Gnome Classic (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, ambiance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.04 gnome classic ambiance font problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131417/12-04-gnome-classic-ambiance-font-problem)

I've just switched to Gnome Classic, but I see some errors with the Ambience theme.

Attached a screenshot. See the tabs:

http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/1187/screenshotfrom201205210h.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in compiz. Use Gnome Classic (no effects) and all those bugs will disappear. You may get back your transparent terminals etc while using (no effects) by enabling metacity compositing:

```
gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool true
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the ambiance theme still does not anticipate the new feature in GNOME 3.4 that introduce the "backdrop" or unfocused state for GTK elements. You need to edit the theme by adding "backdrop" state to several selectors or follow the steps mentioned in [this](http://www.fandigital.com/2012/04/zonmodambiance-fixing-ambiance-default.html) link or directly download the modded theme.