# 12.04 Gnome Classic Launcher Icons on Gnome panel, size and spacing

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

I've been searching the forums and google for a while and nothing seems to work. I have a top and bottom panel in ubuntu 12.04 gnome classic using the default ambiance theme.

My top panel has all my most used apps on but they are all the same size as the panel and touching each other. I'd like to reduce them and space them out a bit.

Anyone managed this and know how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel

Comment: @webid4me Thanks but I had too many problems with Ubuntu 12.04 and now I'm using Fedora 17 Gnome 3 and cairo dock. Best desktop I've ever seen! lol