# Can I change the position of time in gnome-classic panel from top right to top middle?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-classic

The current time is shown in top left in the gnome classic panel. How can I move it to top middle of the panel? The reason that I want to do it is because my eyes move to top right much often than other corners, which strains my eyes.

Any solutions by configuration files, or by some settings via GUI, or by ...?

My OS is 14.04. Thanks.

Here is my panel
[image]

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/76884/1471) is one example that I saw with time in the middle (scroll down to the end of the reply), but I don't know how that was done.

I don't find an option in gnome-tweak-tool for moving time to the middle.

[image]

Comment: If you're on 14.04, GNOME Classic is just GNOME Shell with a bunch of plugins, IIRC. And the default position of the clock in GNOME Shell is in the middle. Install `gnome-tweak-tool` and see if any of extensions are listed.

Comment: Thanks. The default position of the time for me is on the right.  I don't find an option in `gnome-tweak-tool` for moving time to the middle.

Comment: What extensions are listed in `gnome-tweak-tool`?

Comment: @muru see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

@Tim: Can't you just add another clock item to panel? (Alt-right-click on the panel/Add to panel.../Clock) You may have to move the clock (Alt-right-click on the clock/Move/Drag to wanted position) if it shows up in the wrong place (mine ended up to the left). Then I guess you could delete the rightmost clock...or keep it.