# old classic gnome on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, ubuntu-gnome

I'm coming back to linux. When I was using it before it was old good looking familiar gnome time. I'm trying to get this great useful look back on my new system - ubuntu 15.10. I'm installed classic gnome, but it's still not this one gnome which I remember. I'm not able to edit panels (I tired all possible combination alt, ctrl, windows key and mouse clicking). I tried installation of indicator-applet-appmenu, -session and it doesn't help ether. Is there any way to come back to old great look?
If that's not possible then which desktop environment is the best for me if I want have panel with active application (like in windows), and with shortcuts to applications/action (but not the big one like in unity) which I choose, and information about system utilization?

**I read [How to customize the gnome classic panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel) that where I found info about alt windows keys combination but it's not working in any of them**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the gnome classic panel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel)

Comment: With new flashback/fallback as gnome panel, settings have changed a lot. See this for details: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `mate` desktop, it is designed to emulate the old `gnome 2` desktop, you can use these commands to add it to your current 15.10 install

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/utopic-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-core
```

Now log out and click the cog icon and choose `mate`

Alternitivly, there is an official `mate` based version of Ubuntu [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)

[image]

Comment: As you are a new user, if this helped you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others easily find this information.

Comment: thx you very much :) that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @joe33 Please do click the check mark on the left, between the arrows, to say thanks

Comment: Why did this get -1??? Downvoter please explain your self.

Comment: @markkirby : To compensate the (IMHO) undeserved downvote : +1 from me for this good answer, which hopefully will be accepted by joe33, as he said that this is exactly what he was looking for ! :)

Comment: Thanks @cl-netbox I hate these random downvotes withno explination.

Comment: Where is this "cog icon" ?

Comment: @javadba Next to where yo put in your user name.

Comment: Ok. I later remembered that process from when using Classic Gnome. A user not having gone through that process (or not having remembered) would not likely follow this. But i'm upvoting anyways - as an interesting 'plug' for mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ubuntu MATE and make it look like old Gnome 2 setup you had back in Gnome 2 days.

http://ubuntu-mate.org/

Comment: ubuntu mate looks great. Is it possible to install this environment without new installation? I mean just install it on system with gnome classic, and switch environment during log in?

Comment: Yeah you can add it via ppa https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev

Answer (score 0):

Installing classic desktop open the terminal Ctl + Alt + T 
Type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To install settings for old views accept all changes and logout. Select the ubuntu icon displayed on login and select classic view.

Comment: I already tried gnome-session-fallback and flashback but still I have uneditable panels and look quite different than old gnome

Comment: This is the oldest gnome that new systems/kernels are know to support. If you want more customized look check here  http://gnome-look.org/

Answer (score -1):

Correcting the previous post, follow the following commands, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: English, please!